# Rails Telephone field like a date field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I using devise to allow users to register on my website.  I have field for them to put in their telephone number when registering.

I however want to split the telephone field into 3 parts so you put in different parts of the number, kind of like a date.

Is it possible in rails to do something similar like you would with a date?  When you have a date select on a form it gives the field names:

```
model[date(1i)]
model[date(2i)]
model[date(3i)]
```

Is this possible with other fields?

Cheers

Comment: Non-US phone numbers also have a country code in addition to area/city code, exchange (some places) and a local number within the exchange. And phone numbers often need an extension number too. Parsing phone numbers often leads to a poor user experience....be careful.....

Comment: Yea.  I was wanting to avoid building the telephone number after the form has been submitted.  Only people from the US will be registering on the site.  I was wondering if their was a nice and elegant solution other than having a before filter to put it back together.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible to cajole the date_select/select_date family into doing what you want.

You could try to mirror the DateTimeSelector class for your purposes:  https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb

But why not just deal with this in the controller?  You can slice and dice the input any way you want.  If it's a one-time thing, I would do it that way.  Otherwise, it might be worth your time to solve the problem in general, in which case you can make a gem for the world to use...  although I think these 'i' suffixes are only useful for dates and times as far as ActiveRecord is concerned.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I probably will make a wee gem for this as I have made a few sites before and not keen on doing this in the controller everytime.  Cheers!